# Finding number of contiguous subarrays not including certain pairs

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations, combinatorics

How many contiguous subarrays of an array exist such that they do not contain certain pairs of positions of the array? For eg. if array ={11,22,33,45} and if we do not want to include say position number (1,3) and (2,4) then number of contiguous subarrays that exist are 7 which are as follows {{11},{22},{33},{44},{11,22},{22,33},{33,45}}.

My attempt at solving the problem:

If two pairs exist such that {...,a1, ...,a2 ,..,b1, ..,b2} where n is the number of elemnts and (...) indicate that there are elements in between these positions.

1st case :We cannot include {a1,b1} and {a2,b2} then we have to just count the number of possible combinations which is n*(n+1)/2 - no. of possible combinations including {a2,b1} which covers all the possible

case 2. If we cannot include pairs {a1,b2} and {a2,b1} then we just subtract number of possibilties containing {a2,b1} which covers all the possible cases.

3rd case: if we can't include pairs {a1,a2} and {b1,b2} then we have to individually subtract possible subarrays including these positions

The problem I'm facing is I am not able to derive a formula and extend these cases to more than 2 pairs to count the number of possible solutions even after formulating the cases. So, I need help regarding that.

Source: This is an interview question asked to my friend which he could not answer.

Comment: Are you looking for a formula to determine the number of such subarrays or for an algorithm to generate the subarrays (which you can then count)?

Comment: I am looking for a formula/code to just count the number of such subarrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so let's look again at the array {11,22,33,44}.

Let's say you're trying to find all subarrays starting with 11 (index=1). Now you only need to look at restrictions (a,b) where index<=a and b is minimal, because if you have e.g. (2,3) this automatically implies (1,4) or (2,4).

To find the minimal b, use the following code (I used C#):

```
public static int  findRestrictingIndex(int currentIndex, List<Tuple<int, int>> restrictions)
    {
        int result = int.MaxValue;
        foreach (var pair in restrictions)
        {
            if (currentIndex <= pair.Item1)
            {
                if (pair.Item2 < result)
                    result = pair.Item2;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

If you run this code, you'll receive 3 (from (1,3)) as a result. The number of arrays starting with 11 is then 3-1=2, because you can add numbers to 11 up to excluding index 3.

Do this for every index and you'll be done:

```
int arrayLength = 4;

//excluded positions, zero-based
List<Tuple<int, int>> restrictions = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
restrictions.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(0, 2));
restrictions.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 3));
restrictions.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(4, 4));    //dummy element when there is no restriction

int numOfSubarrays = 0;
for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < arrayLength; currentIndex++)
{
    numOfSubarrays += findRestrictingIndex(currentIndex, restrictions) - currentIndex;
}
Console.WriteLine(numOfSubarrays);
```